# Getting key and respective value in ng-repeat using Selenium and Python

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, python

Being new to `Selenium`, I have been trying to figure how to extract the value corresponding to the key under the `ng-repeat`, in my case, the key is `status`.

The partial page is as follow:

```
<div ng-repeat="(key, value) in lastResult" class="ng-scope">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-4">
                  <span class="key pull-right ng-binding">status</span>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-8">
                  <span class="value ng-binding" ng-class="isUrl(value) ? 'ellipsis' : ''" ng-bind-html="value | highlight">1</span>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

<div ng-repeat="(key, value) in lastResult" class="ng-scope">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-4">
                  <span class="key pull-right ng-binding">type</span>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-8">
                  <span class="value ng-binding" ng-class="isUrl(value) ? 'ellipsis' : ''" ng-bind-html="value | highlight">standard</span>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
```

Page can contain many other `ng-repeats`, but I am only interested in the value of the `status`, which is `1` in the above sample code.

I'm using selenium with `python 3`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea here is to apply the findAll - filter - extract pattern.

Find all:

```
ng_scopes = driver.find_elements_by_class("ng-scope")
```

Filter:

ng_scopes_with_status_one = [ng_scope for ng_scope in ng_scopes if ng_scopes.find_element_by_css_selector(".col-xs-8 span").text == "1"]

Extract:

```
ng-repeat_value = ng_scopes_with_status_one[0].get_attribute("ng-repeat")
```

Comment: Hi João, thank you very much for your reply. I met another hurdle as in the landing page is full of javascript which I have no idea which javascript generate the abovementioned page... I guess I have to KIV this project and move on to another.